# connecting to DB from custom php file

Tags: database

I want to connect to database and get some values. I have a custom .php file and I want to make my connection in a secure and efficient way. What is the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: if you want this for AJAX, use this : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: What exactly do you want to access in the database? You already have a secure connection to it via the WordPress core. And, unless you're using some kind of custom table and whatnot, WP already has functions that you can use to access that data.

Answer (score 3):

You're must load WP-load function
To do that you need to require wp-load file, so if, your custom file is in theme it shoudl look like somethink like that:

```
$wp_load = '../../../../../wp-load.php';
if ( file_exists( $wp_load ) ) {
    require_once( $wp_load );
}else{
    die('no-load');
}
```

You could also set const SHORTINIT to true to minimalize WP loads... it's helpfull if you dont need full WP crap etc, butw you can load WP elements ... depend of your needs

```
function wp_load_utils ( ) {
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-walker.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/l10n.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/script-loader.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/general-template.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/link-template.php' );
   //require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/shortcodes.php' );
   wp_functionality_constants();
}

function wp_load_session ( ) {
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php');
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-user.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-roles.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-role.php' );
   require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/session.php' );
   wp_cookie_constants();
}
```

Below my custom ajax file that handle Ajax request instead of admin-ajax.php, it is much faster ... like standard need about 200-400ms to hit admin.php output, this using only shortint  is able to do it under 50ms

https://gist.github.com/isuke01/a4d22fc19240928597a0dfed1af791e8